# How to show just the day and month in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime

I want to show a list of records in chronological order in PHP. For example,

**15 Sep 2015**

or, say just

**15 Sep**

In the MySQL database, the date/time is stored in the following way:

**2015-09-15 23:19:13**

Is there an existing function in PHP, which can help me do it?

Comment: [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) php([strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) + [date](http://php.net/date))

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Sorting by chronologial order or formatting your dates?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you trying to show all of the records from a specific date in chronological order? Does the year matter or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use two of PHP's date functions. date() and strtotime(). One within the other.

You do the following:

```
$dateStr = date("j M Y", strtotime(mysql_date_string_here));
```

There you will get the date in the format you described above.

Comment: Thanks Mark. It works!

Answer (score 0):

You better use both mysql and PHP. First in your mysql query use an 'order by date_column' clause. That will return the records in the right order.

Then when you're getting the results in PHP use [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) or [DateTime::format()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) to correctly format the dates.